# Having a single application name, and not separate activity names

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an android application with three activities: Loading, Main, Credits.

But when I try to run and look into the emulator, I have three icons: Loading, Main, Credits.

How can I just have a single Application name? And where do I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in android manifest file in application level.

**android:label="@string/app_name"**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Loading"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main" />
    <activity android:name=".Credits" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you just need to set `<intent-filter>` for only one `Activity` other `Activities` don't need this tag.